# How to avoid a linebreak before a comma?

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation

I just had a problem with a linebreak after a word ending with a hyphen which was followed by a comma.

This example shows the problem:
*(The example is constructed, but this just occurred to me in a real text!)*

```
    \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

aaDas ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz. Es gibt zeit-, temperatur-,  und weggesteuerte Verfahren ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz.Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz.Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz.Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz.Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz.

    \end{document}
```

[image: example image]

As I can not imagine any scenario where a comma at the beginning of a line could make sense, I wonder how I could tell LaTeX to absolutely avoid that.

Comment: The problem, I suspect, is not so much with the comma as with the hyphen. There should be some way of producing a hyphen without TeX interpreting it as a valid place to break a word across a line.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap: you're absolutely right. I just put it this way, as IMHO a comma should be never typeset at the beginning of a line, at least I could not imagine a case that makes sense at the moment.

Comment: If you use LuaTeX, we could provide you a solution that forbids a line break before a comma.

Comment: @Patrick: I'm using the "normal" `pdflatex` - so I'm afraid this is not an option (at least for me).

Comment: Notice that this is incorrect punctuation. In German, there is no comma before “und” in enumerations. (Unless they changed that with the Rechtschreibreform but I doubt that.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph While it's true that the comma is incorrect before "und", this is unrelated to OP's LaTeX problem.

Comment: @Jan Oh, absolutely. I just wanted to point it out because we’re here on tex.sx where people usually care about typography and punctuation, and because I’m a know-it-all. ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph: you're absolutely right that the comma before "und" is not correct, however without the "und" my example did not work and I did not have the time to create a gramatically perfect sentence which was also useful to demonstrate the problem. :-)

Comment: @topskip The LuaTeX solution would be very interesting, Should I open a new question for it?

Comment: @georgd yes, please do so, although I cannot guarantee anything.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should use `"~` for that. See the documentation for babel (`texdoc babel`).

```
aaDas ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz. Es gibt zeit"~, temperatur"~, und weggesteuerte Verfahren ein Absatz.
Das ist ein Absatz.Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz.Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz.Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein
Absatz.Das ist ein Absatz. Das ist ein Absatz.
```

Comment: Is there any equivalent for english texts?

Comment: @barbaz you should ask a new question

Comment: well it would be pretty much the same question - since the  questioner didn't restrict his problem to german documents in any way. Just the example texts are in german. Also your answer should mention that it works only for [german]{babel} (and a few other languages, however, not english)

Comment: @barbaz The implicit restriction is set by the option `ngerman` to the package `babel`. Feel free to edit my question!

Answer (score 5):

Enclosing the offending word in an `\mbox` works:

```
\mbox{temperatur-,}
```

I assume there is a neater way if there are lots of these hyphens where you don't want to allow breaks...

Comment: thanks - as you're writing, this is a one-time-workaround. However as I consider this (=comma at beginning of line) a total no-go, it should be just "forbidden" globally, IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Use my macro `\nobreakseq`

```
\def \nobreakseq {\nobreak \hskip 0pt \hbox}

Es gibt zeit\nobreakseq{-,} temperatur\nobreakseq{-,}  und weggesteuerte Verfahren ein Absatz.
```

It is better than `\hbox{temperatur-,}` or `\mbox{temperatur-,}` beacuse of `\hbox{temperatur-,}` does not allow any hyphenation.

Comment: I would have thought that avoiding hyphenation in `temperatur` would be a good thing in this case...

Comment: @Seamus: indeed, two hyphens in a word is to be avoided I think.