# How to prevent a stranded comma on the next line?

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation

In this document, where I am replicating my original document in order to get the issue I am highlighting here, a comma is stranded on the next line:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = .5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{gb4e}
    \exewidth{(23)}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex The suffix \textit{-ung-}, on the other hand, clearly undergoes vowel harmony here, cf.\ \textit{áttong-}, \textit{brǿðrongr}, \textit{fjórðong-}, and \textit{konong-} vs.\ \textit{systrungr} and \textit{þriðung-}. These words occur frequently and there are no exceptions.\\
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why does this occur and what is the best way to fix/prevent it?

There's a similar problem raised in [How to avoid a linebreak before a comma?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29884/how-to-avoid-a-linebreak-before-a-comma), but the accepted answer refers to the [`babel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) package, which I am not using (I use polyglossia), and to its documentation, whose current version doesn't mention the `"~` sequence given in the answer.

Comment: mentioning shorthands, you can activate babel shorthands in polyglossia. I just don't know what it is from the top of my head. Should be something like `babelshorthands=on`. -> From the package: `\DeclareOption{babelshorthands}{\setkeys{polyglossia}{babelshorthands=true}}`

Comment: You could use `\mbox{-}` where you wanted to avoid mis-hyphenation.

Comment: there is a `\nobreakdash` defined in `amsmath` for this express purpose.  if the description of the problem in the user guide (`texdoc amsmath`, p.9) sounds like it would do what you need, i'll be happy to define an analog that shouldn't step on the toes of the class file and packages shown in your example.  (it would not be automatic.)

Comment: On a completely different matter, you shoud define a sematic command instead of repeating `textit` all the time.

Comment: @barbarabeeton In theory, yes, that sounds like what I want. But egreg says ``mbox`` is the way to go, and who am I to disagree? ``:)``

Comment: @Johannes_B Why is repeating ``\textit`` worse than repeating some other command I define as equivalent to ``\textit``?

Comment: Semantic markup. You use section, right? You could just as well repeat `\refstepcounter{section}\large\bfseries\thesection~this is my section title\par\normalfont\normalsize\noindent` over and over again. Or whatever the definition of section in detail is.

Comment: Having one command for one job, you can later decide to have all occurences of `affix` to use `slshape` isntead of `itshape`. Something else.

Comment: @Johannes_B OK, I accept your second comment here, not your first ``:)`` (Since the length of ``\textit`` is equivalent to the length of some other equivalent command).

Comment: @sverre Both have the same point, semantic markup. With section, the replacement text is just a bit more complicated. And not at all semantic. `memoir` and the `KOMA` classes provide hooks and stuff to define `sectionfont` and similar stuff.

Comment: @Sverre `hyphencomma.sty` from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268794/how-to-avoid-a-linebreak-before-a-comma-in-lualatex works fine with your example in LuaLaTeX

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't want to use `\textit{...}`, because TeX could be willing to hyphenate the affix. Better defining a macro for this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[paper = a4paper, margin = .5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{gb4e}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\exewidth{(23)}

\newcommand{\affix}[1]{\mbox{\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex The suffix \affix{-ung-}, on the other hand, clearly undergoes vowel harmony here,
cf.\ \affix{áttong-}, \affix{brǿðrongr}, \affix{fjórðong-}, and \affix{konong-} vs.\
\affix{systrungr} and \affix{þriðung-}. These words occur frequently and there are no
exceptions.

\ex The suffix \affix{-ung-}, on the other hand, clearly undergoes vowel harmony here,
cf.~\affix{áttong-}, \affix{brǿðrongr}, \affix{fjórðong-}, and \affix{konong-} vs.\@
\affix{systrungr} and \affix{þriðung-}. These words occur frequently and there are no
exceptions.
\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

I have presented two ways for inputting the text. Instead of “backslash space” it's better `\@`; between `cf.` and the next word probably a tie would be better.

In this case you get an overfull box, but that's life: wait until the document is in final form before fixing these small problems. And don't use 14pt type unless it's a children's book or it is for visually impaired people. Note also that `\\` at the end is useless (and wrong).

[image]

Comment: Actually, ``\mbox`` is what I used in my document, I just assumed (or hoped) there was a better way. To your other comments: Why is ``\@`` better than ``\`` (cf. [these answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/is-a-period-after-an-abbreviation-the-same-as-an-end-of-sentence-period))? I use 14pt in my presentation handouts, where I print two pages on each side of a landscape oriented page. I find 14pt to be the best size for that.

Comment: To your last comment:  You're right that ``\\`` is useless in this MWE, but I generally use it in my ``{exe}`` environments in my presentation handouts when I want extra space between my ``\ex`` items - which I don't always want (hence why I don't assign such spacing globally).

Comment: @Sverre `-` is a feasible break point, so either you mask it in a box or add a penalty after it. But considering you could even get a break after the first hyphen in `-ung-`, the `\mbox` way seems best.

Comment: I would have preferred for LaTeX to not allow breaks after ``-`` if a punctuation character like ``,``, ``.``, etc. followed, because I cannot imagine where that would be a desired outcome.

Comment: @Sverre Send an email to Knuth. `;-)`

Comment: I would, if it weren't for the fact that he only accepts bug reports, not feature requests :)

Comment: One person's _feature_ is another person's _bug_.