# Why does TeX break the line between -- and ,?

Tags: line-breaking

I have the following `\hbox`, and if I unbox it and put it to a paragraph (or when I just type `aaa --, bbb` or `aaa --\nobreak, bbb`), TeX is breaking the line between `--` and `,`.

```
> \box0=
\hbox(6.88875+1.94443)x46.1109
.\T1/lmr/m/n/10 a
.\T1/lmr/m/n/10 a
.\T1/lmr/m/n/10 a
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\T1/lmr/m/n/10 ^^U (ligature --)
.\T1/lmr/m/n/10 ,
.\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.\T1/lmr/m/n/10 b
.\T1/lmr/m/n/10 b
.\T1/lmr/m/n/10 b
```

My questions:

1. Why does such a line break happen?
2. Why doesn't `\nobreak` disable the line break?
3. Is it possible to fix it so that no line break happens when the source file contains `--,` (without any wrappers like `\hbox` or `\mbox`)?

Comment: Probably the same problem as addressed in [How to avoid a linebreak before a comma?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29884/how-to-avoid-a-linebreak-before-a-comma) and [How to prevent a stranded comma on the next line?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233638/how-to-prevent-a-stranded-comma-on-the-next-line).

Comment: @Sverre saw your comment after I'd answered but I think I'll let my answer stand, it's not immediately obvious that rules about breaking at `-` also apply to  ligatures ending with that character `--`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TeX adds an implicit `\discretionary{}{}{}` item after the `\hyphenchar` in the current font or any ligature that ends with that character (TeXbook, p. 95, last dangerous paragraph); the default value of `\hyphenchar` is 45, which in ASCII is exactly the hyphen.

Saying `\nobreak` after `-` does nothing, because at the top of page 95 there's the list of places where a line break is possible and discretionary items are included; so a break at the implicit discretionary break is possible and the penalty issued by `\nobreak` is discarded.

If you don't want to have a discretionary break after an en-dash, you can use `\textendash` that directly calls the character by number, so no ligature is involved.

Comment: How do I make `\showbox` show this implicit `\discretionary{}{}{}`?

Comment: @pts I don't think you can. The comment `(ligature --)` tells you about it.

Comment: @pts You probably realized that the answer to your question 3 is *no*.

Comment: Thanks for this documentation on the automatic discretionary. I fixed [my answer on how to get non-breakable dashes without hindering hyphenation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282420/43807) to work around this (using the T1 encoding’s 0x7F character), and it works successfully for the internal document at work.

Answer (score 6):

You can hide the ligature in a box. (It would have been helpful to have supplied an example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{2cm}

\begin{document}

aa--bb aa--bb aa--bb aa--bb aa--bb aa--bb aa--bb 


aa\mbox{--}bb aa\mbox{--}bb aa\mbox{--}bb aa\mbox{--}bb aa\mbox{--}bb aa\mbox{--}bb aa\mbox{--}bb 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Unfortunately it doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: @pts not sure the first two are answerable, it happens because tex is programmed to add a break point after ligatures ending with hyphenchar, `\nobreak` doesn't work as it's not in the right place, it is after the break just as if you go `\linebreak\mbox{}\nobreak` the break can happen at the first penalty. If it were breaking at a space you could put `\nobreak` _before_ the space but that doesn't work here.

Answer (score 6):

Egreg has already explained why you get the break. Beside  `\textendash` you could also use  `\nobreakdash` (from amsmath) to avoid it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength\textwidth{2cm}
\begin{document}

aa --, aa --, aa --, aa --, aa --, aa --, aa --,

\bigskip

aa --, aa \textendash, aa --, aa --, aa --, aa --, aa --,

\bigskip

aa --, aa \nobreakdash--, aa --, aa --, aa --, aa --, aa --,

\end{document}
```

[image]